# Add a Chronometer Ticklistener and change the text color in a custom Android Notification

Tags: java, android

I create a foreground service with a custom notification and want to add a `TickListener` and change the text color of the chronometer. The notification is displayed as defined in the XML file and can not be changed afterwards. If I change the text color or add a listener nothing happens.

```
public void onCreate() 
{
  super.onCreate();
  notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.service_location_gps_notification, null);
chronometer = layout.findViewById(R.id.chronometer_Service_Location_GPS_Notification);
  chronometer.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
  chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(chronometerOnClickListener);
  chronometer.setText("00:00:00");
  remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.service_location_gps_notification);

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) 
  {
    CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
  }
  startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
}

private Notification getNotification() 
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceLocationGPS.class);
  PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

  PendingIntent activityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

  int drawable;
  String modus;

  if(FragmentDistanceLocation.DISTANCE_MODE) 
  {
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView_Service_Location_GPS_Notification_Titel, String.valueOf(this.meter) + " Meter");
    modus = "Strecken Modus";
    drawable = R.drawable.ic_directions_run_white_24dp;
    chronometer.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorGreen));
  } else {
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView_Service_Location_GPS_Notification_Titel, this.locationname);
    modus = "HealthPoint Modus";
    drawable = R.drawable.ic_fitness_center_white_24dp;
    chronometer.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorBlue));
  }
  remoteViews.setChronometer(chronometer.getId(), SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timerSeconds, null, true);
  NotificationCompat.Builder notificationCompatBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentIntent(activityPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.logo_group_background, "Workout beenden",
                    servicePendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(drawable)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setCustomContentView(remoteViews)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSubText(modus)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
  return notificationCompatBuilder.build();
}

Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener chronometerOnClickListener = new 
Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
    long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
    int h = (int) (time / 3600000);
    int m = (int) (time - h * 3600000) / 60000;
    int s = (int) (time - h * 3600000 - m * 60000) / 1000;
    String hh = h < 10 ? "0" + h : h + "";
    String mm = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m + "";
    String ss = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s + "";
    chronometer.setText(hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss);
  }
};
```

This is `layout_Service_Location_GPS_Notification.xml`:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_Service_Location_GPS_Notification_Titel"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:text="Strecke"
        android:textColor="@color/ActionbarColor" />

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer_Service_Location_GPS_Notification"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorGreen"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_22sdp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post but I was looking for an answer as well and found one. Not sure if this would help your particular issue, but calling chronometer.setbase(SystemClock.elapsedRealTime()) updated any format changes. On your case it looked like you needed to set the chronometer's internal time. I won't spend time trying to help that specific issue since again, its an old post lol